# Know who cloned the project to their local system in Gitlab

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a project with 20 members in it. Is there any possibility to know `who` clonned the project into their Local system? So that I can trace out undone updations in the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count to number of `clones` can be known in `Github` as [Clone Graphs](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-traffic-to-a-repository/).

But in `Gitlab`, it is still a [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21743)

But `who` clonned the project, CANNOT be known in both hosting sites i.e., Github and Gitlab .

Comment: Yes, that was the gist of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No: as I explain in "[Definition of “downstream” and “upstream”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)", an upstream repo (GitLab) does not know about the downstream repo (cloned by users)

You will trace what is pushed back to your original repo.

Since [GitLab 8.5.2](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/03/gitlab-8-dot-5-dot-2-released/), you can list forks of a repo, but if your collaborators are developer on your repo, they don't need to fork it. A simple clone is enough: they can push back directly.