# Can we see cloned project counts or who cloned the project in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I am a private project Maintainer and want to see how many times project is cloned by developers.

Comment: As per my opinion, it is for git hub, same applies for git lab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes the same applies for `gitlab`, you can't see the cloners and here is the link to that question: [Know who cloned the project to their local system in Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960776/know-who-cloned-the-project-to-their-local-system-in-gitlab)